# Locking cells in Excel from autoedit

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I lock cells with equations in excel so excel doesn't autoedit them?
Freeze seems to have no effect and protect mode is too random.

By autoedit I mean that the formulas are modified when I move cells around in the worksheet. I have one formula side of the worksheet and one with input data which Im occationally thoughtless enough to cut and paste around causing problems with the formulas.

Comment: "so excel doesn't autoedit them? " - what do you exactly mean? Maybe also add some examples (when Excel "autoedited" your data in a wrong way)?

Comment: more details are needed to give a correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to make the formulas *non-relative* by adding a `$` sign in front of the row and/or column, as needed (not just everywhere- just as needed!).
For example, if you have the formula `=B1*D6`, and you want to use always the top row, no matter where the formula goes, use `=B$1*D6` instead. If this formula gets copied ten rows down, it becomes `=B$1*D16`.

Generally, for each formula you ever enter, you should think about which rows/columns in it are fixed (add the $), and which are relative (don't add a $). Excel supports that with the F4 key; pressing it in the middle of entering formulas will modify the current cell entered to various combinations of relative/non-relative.
Getting used to do that every time avoids this kind of copy/paste trouble later.